# USB C monitors no longer working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, intel

I have two ASUS ProArt PA27C monitors and a 16" MacBook Pro 2019 (i9, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M, Intel UHD Graphics 630, Ventura 13.1). The MacBook previously connected to the two monitors via daisy-chained USB-C.

Now when I connect it to even one monitor, the monitor stays black, and the built-in display also turns black. I tried mirroring my built-in display to my iPad to see if I could still do some diagnosis with the external monitor plugged in, but the mirroring freezes while the display is plugged in. The only thing that I can think of that has changed was upgrading to Ventura.

My newer M1 (company) MacBook still connects to both monitors fine. The 2019 MBP can also connect to at least one monitor happily via HDMI.

I've tried rebooting, resetting PRAM, resetting SMC, safe boot, etc. I don't know what to try next.

Comment: I'd suggest you get the hardware checked out at an Apple Store, or local Apple-authorised shop.